# Array length after unshift is wrong

Tags: javascript

It's basic so forgive me.

```
var localProductPhotos=[];
```

This array is filled with new products *by index* not by `push`:

```
localProductPhotos[id]= dic["file"] ;
```

Later i have a situation ***where i insert values using the above line*** to indexes `0,1,3`, and i would like to **shift** index `3` to be the first element (index 0 ):

```
  localProductPhotos.unshift(localProductPhotos.splice(editedPhoto, 1)[0]);
```

Problem is, that in this specific case where `editedPhoto=3`, **the array length will count 4** : `localProductPhotos.length = 4`, not 3.

I guess it's because it still count that index 3 not as null ?

How to fix this ?

Comment: actually, given the state you presented, and the code, the result is an array length 6, with the value at y moved to the front as required ... perhaps the state of the array is NOT as you claim - but nothing in your code should result in the array being any less than **6**

Comment: I think i did not present the array right, when i said null, i mean i didn't put any value after y, and between x and y.

Comment: whatever, it starts length 6, it'll end length 6 - post some MCVE that shows otherwise

Comment: Please see my edit, because it is obviously not 6, but 4.

Comment: but yes, if you have values in indexes 0, 1 and 3, then the length of the array is 4 - and that's the case even if editedPhoto is 0 or 1, not just 3

Comment: Sorry ! really sorry, i fixed it to insert. insert the same way i show array[3]=...

Comment: Perhaps a simple array isn't going to be useful for your design, since the ordinal position of the data is not important anyway - you insert it with id:1, and it's not guaranteed to stay at index 1 because you move things around, so why use an array

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate? i would like to have an arary where i can push values to any index i want, then to be able to push some index to the begining, and still count the real length.

Comment: use filter to remove the `undefined` elements ... AFTER moving things with your unshift/splice, then `localProductPhotos=localProductPhotos.filter(x => x !== undefined)` - of course, if subsequently you add something with id = 2, you will clobber what is in that spot, which was originally id=1

Comment: ah i see, thanks, sounds like my design is bad anyway.

Comment: @JaromandaX that's not the same, here they are dealing with a sparse array. To remove these empty slots they could do `arr.filter(_=>true)`  but `.filter(x => x !== undefined)` will remove non empty slots

Comment: are you sure that will work AFTER the unshift/splice? (oh, right, yes it does)

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, it works after. They're still empty slots

Comment: Possibly a good application for a circularly linked list.  Each element has a forward and back pointer and a (possibly empty) payload, and the collection has a head pointer representing the start.  To move an element from last to first, just backup the head pointer.

Comment: @Kaiido - thanks, I did not realise that about empty slots (good to learn something)

Comment: @JaromandaX tbh I also learned something, I though `map` also was avoiding empty slots (and thus would return a clean array) while it seems it returns a sparse array, even though the callback hasn't been called on empty slots)

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I learned something also. I will change my design completely.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use a data structure to store your localProductPhotos, an array of objects with an `order` property each of them.

For instance:

```
let a = [
  {
    order: 1,
    color: "yellow"
  }, {
    order: 0,
    color: "red"
  }, {
    order: 2,
    color: "green"
  }
];
```

Then you need an ordering function to pass to the Array prototype `order` method.

```
const ord = (key, order = 'asc') => {
  return (a, b) => {
    if(!a.hasOwnProperty(key) || !b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return null; //or any error code.
    }

    let r = (a[key] > b[key]) ? 1 : -1;

    return (order == 'desc') ? (r * -1) : r;
  }
}
```

So when the user changes the order of the element, you only have to modify the value of the 'order' property in the objects.

Then print them in order, use something like:

```
aOrderedAsc = a.sort(ord('order'));
```

or:

```
aOrderedDesc = a.sort(ord('order', 'desc'));
```

Comment: thanks but i don't want to remove free slots , i want to keep the map (this array is "visual" to the user), so they can play with it, adding moving and removing stuff.

Comment: @hkrly have a look at my edited answer I hope it'll be useful :)